# MySQL query from query in PHP

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli, subquery

I am trying to find the most efficient way to query the results of a query and every one of the solutions I am finding online produce a 1064 error. I don't understand what I am doing wrong.

The latest iteration I have tried is the following:

```
$sql = "SELECT keys.* FROM (SELECT * FROM calendar WHERE event_key LIKE '".$eventKey."%') keys WHERE event='".$eventTitle."'";
```

The previous one I tried was:

```
$sql = "SELECT *(events) FROM (SELECT * AS events FROM calendar WHERE event_key LIKE '201974000') WHERE event='Event Name' AS lineitems";
```

The error that I got on this last one in phpMyAdmin was:

> **SQL query:**  
> SELECT *(events) FROM (SELECT * AS events FROM calendar
>   WHERE event_key LIKE '201974000') AS lineitems LIMIT 0, 25
>   **MySQL said:**
>
> 1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use
>   near '(events) FROM (SELECT * AS events FROM calendar WHERE event_key
>   LIKE '201974000'' at line 1

What I am trying to do is query my database like so:

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM calendar WHERE event_key LIKE '".$eventKey."%'";
```

...and then query those results like so:

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM <<RESULTS>> WHERE event='".$eventTitle."'";
```

Where do I have it wrong?

NOTE:
I also tried:

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM calendar WHERE (event_key LIKE '".$eventKey."%' AND event='".$event."'";
```

**HERE IS THE COMPLETE PHP FILE:**

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Untitled Document</title>
</head>

<body>
    <?php

    function imageCorrection($string){
        $find = array("file/d/","/view?usp=drive_web");
        $replace = array("uc?id=","");
        $string = str_replace($find,$replace,$string);
        return $string;
    }

    function seoUrl($string){
        $src = 'àáâãäçèéêëìíîïñòóôõöøùúûüýÿßÀÁÂÃÄÇÈÉÊËÌÍÎÏÑÒÓÔÕÖØÙÚÛÜÝ';
    $rep = 'aaaaaceeeeiiiinoooooouuuuyysAAAAACEEEEIIIINOOOOOOUUUUY';
        $find = array("the","and");
        $replace = array("");
        $string = strtr(utf8_decode($string),utf8_decode($src),$rep);
        $string = strtolower($string);
        $string = str_replace("");
        $string = str_replace($find,$replace,$string);
        $string = preg_replace("/[^a-z0-9\s._-]/","",$string);
        $string = preg_replace("/[\s._-]+/"," ",$string);
        $string = preg_replace("/[\s]/","-",$string);
        $string = "/events/".$string;
        if($string = "/events/"){
            $string = null;
        }
        return $string;
    }

    $year = date('Y');
    $lastYear = date('Y',strtotime("last year"));
    $nextYear = date('Y',strtotime("next year"));
    date_default_timezone_set('America/Anchorage');
    $eventTimeZone = new DateTimeZone("America/Anchorage");
    $currentTime = new DateTime("now",$eventTimeZone);
    $eventTimeOffset = $eventTimeZone->getOffset($currentTime);
    use Sabre\VObject;
    include '../../vendor/autoload.php';

    $vcalendar = VObject\Reader::read(fopen('https://calendar.google.com/calendar/ical/i8j5d94tpgnnqu6h8q3mt6uc48%40group.calendar.google.com/public/basic.ics','r'));
    $vcalendar = $vcalendar->expand(new DateTime('2018-01-01'), new DateTime('2020-12-31'));

    $servername = "localhost";
    $username    = "#########";
    $password    = "#########";
    $dbname  = "#########";

    // Create connection
    $connection = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);

    // Check connection
    if ($connection->connect_error){
        die("Connection to calendar failed: " . $connection->connect_error);
    }

    foreach($vcalendar->VEVENT as $event){
        $eventTitle = $event->SUMMARY;
        $eventStart = strtotime($event->DTSTART);
        $eventEnd   = strtotime($event->DTEND);
        $eventDesc  = $event->DESCRIPTION;
        $eventLocat = $event->LOCATION;
        $eventImage = imageCorrection($event->ATTACH);
        $eventKey   = date('YzB',$eventStart);
        $eventURL   = seoUrl($eventTitle);
        echo $eventKey."<br>";
        echo $eventTitle."<br>";
        echo $eventURL."<br>";
        echo $eventDesc."<br>";
        echo $eventLocat."<br>";
        echo $eventImage."<br>";
        echo date('m-d-Y h:ia',$eventStart)."<br>";
        echo date('m-d-Y h:ia',$eventEnd)."<br>";


        $sql = "SELECT * FROM calendar WHERE event_key LIKE '".$eventKey."%' AND event='".$eventTitle."'";
        $update = "UPDATE calendar SET url='".$eventURL."',image='".$eventImage."',description='".$eventDesc."',location='".$eventLocat."',start_date='".$eventStart."',end_date='".$eventEnd."',color='FFB819' WHERE (event_key LIKE '".$eventKey."%' AND event='".$eventTitle."')";
        $insert = "INSERT INTO calendar VALUES ('".$eventNum."', '".$eventTitle."', '".$eventURL."', '".$eventImage."', '".$eventDesc."', '".$eventLocat."', '".$eventStart."', '".$eventEnd."', 'FFB819')";

        $query = $connection->query($sql);
        echo "Query Results: ".$query->num_rows."  EventKey: ".$eventKey."  ".$eventTitle."<br>";
        if($query->num_rows > 0){
            echo "Rows: ==".$query->num_rows."<br>";
            $updateQUERY = $connection->query($update);
        }else{
            echo "Rows: #".$query->num_rows."<br>";
            $key = "SELECT * FROM calendar WHERE event_key LIKE '".$eventKey."%'";
            $query2 = $connection->query($key);
            if($query2->num_rows > 0){
                $eventNum = $query2->num_rows;
                $eventNum++;
                echo "Query 2 Rows: ##".$eventNum."<br>";
            }else{
                $eventNum = 0;
                echo "Query 2 Rows: #".$eventNum."<br>";
            }
            if($eventNum < 10){
                $eventNum = "00".$eventNum;
            }elseif($eventNum < 100){
                $eventNum = "0".$eventNum;
            }
            $eventNum = $eventKey.$eventNum;
            echo "Event#: ".$eventNum."<br>";
            $insertQUERY = $connection->query($insert);
        }
        echo "==============================================================================<br>";
    }


    ?>
</body>
</html>
```

All of the echo lines are there for testing purposes only to follow the execution of the code.

Comment: Please see about sql injection and the importance of prepared and bound queries

Comment: Incidentally, filtering arrays client side is straightforward process.Here's an example that I particularly like... https://metafizzy.co/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it is redundant running a sub-query in this instance. Since you want to simply find **where event = '$eventTitle'** on the result of your first query only, it is just as saying:

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM calendar WHERE `event_key` LIKE '%$eventKey%' AND `event` = '$eventTitle'";
```

NB: notice I didn't use the dot concatenation; because the double quotes surrounding the whole query allows PHP variables within.

Your last trial was close to being right, but you didn't need to open a bracket and even if you wanted to use it, you didn't close it.

Comment: That doesn't seem to be correct. When I remove the periods and run it in the browser it gives me >> This page isn’t working #### is currently unable to handle this request.
HTTP ERROR 500

Comment: Please share the revised query you're trying to run. 
However, the 'double quote' advantage has been a standing one for a very long time in PHP..

Comment: I am going to share the entire php document above. When I paste the line of code (minus the $sql =) into phpMyAdmin and replace the variables with actual text, the code executes perfectly. When I run it by accessing the php file on the web, it doesn't query the database properly.

Comment: I think you should paste it. The problem might be on another line.

Comment: I think I've found the problem. When looking at the $eventKey that is being echoed out to the page and looking at the event_key in the database, they don't match.

Comment: Oh... Okay, great! But I think for proper error_reporting and avoid having headaches debugging in a blind environment, turn on your 'display_errors'  in your php.ini file.

And also, you might wanna use 'try and catch' ...

Above all, glad you found the error. And the double-quote without periods is a correct approach too.

Comment: Thank you for the tips. Everything I know about php (which isn't much!) I've taught myself so I really appreciate learning new things like this.